# A definitive panacea for copy vs view in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Ok guys! I've suffered a lot because of how finicky Pandas is on whether the DataFrame is its copy or view. I just want to use an indexing that would ensure me that I'm always getting the pandas DataFrame like I get any other variables in Python, nothing fancy, no BS, just straight forward old-school data access and assignment.
e.g.

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
x[3] = 5
print(x)
[0, 1, 2, 5, 4]
```

That's all I want to do. What is the surefire way to make sure this happens, I'm not too worried about efficiency here.

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5),
    list('abcde'), list('ABCDE'))

# this is the problem assignment that is causing the warning
d1 = df[['A', 'B']]

d1.loc['a', 'A'] = 99
```

[image]

## Use `loc` to create a copy instead

```
d2 = df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']]

d2.loc['a', 'A'] = 99

d2

    A   B
a  99   1
b   5   6
c  10  11
d  15  16
e  20  21
```

## Ways to copy a dataframe that cause the warning

Define a function that try's to make an assignment on the first element of the dataframe that is passed.

```
def try_assignment(df):
    df.iloc[0, 0] = 1000
```

Now let's test some cases

### Warning `True`

- `try_assignment(df[['A']])`
- `try_assignment(df[:-1])`
- `try_assignment(df.iloc[:, :-1])`

### Warning `False`

- `try_assignment(df.loc[:, 'A'])`
- `try_assignment(df[:])`
- `try_assignment(df.loc[:, df.columns[:-1]])`
- `try_assignment(df.loc[df.index[1:], df.columns[1:]])`
- `try_assignment(df[['A']].copy())`

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, it seems that using df.loc[x, y] solves most of the problems. But I can't do df.loc[-1,y], I need to use iloc for that. Is there a way to access via indexing like '-1, -2' but still not get a warning?